Exclude NavigationBarItems from Image Rendering SwiftUI
Inside of my drawing view, there are three items at the top of the screen: Back Button, Title, and Save Button. When the user presses the save button, an image of the screen is rendered and then saved to the camera roll. Currently, I am having the image trimmed so that those items aren't in the screenshot. But I am looking for a way where I can just exclude the save button and back button so that the title still shows in the saved image
 var body: some View {
    VStack {
        CanvasWithBackgroundView(data: data ?? Data(), id: id ?? UUID(), backgroundImageName: backgroundImageName)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
            //.navigationBarTitle(title ?? "Untitled", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) // Hide the default back button
            .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton, trailing: saveButton)
            .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                            customTitleView
                        }
                    }
    }
    
}


func saveToCameraRoll() {
        guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
              let window = windowScene.windows.first else {
            return
        }
        
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: window.bounds)
        let image = renderer.image { context in
            window.drawHierarchy(in: window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        
        // Trim the image
        let imageSize = image.size
        let scale = image.scale
        let width = imageSize.width * scale
        let height = imageSize.height * scale
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 139, width: width, height: height - 115)
        if let croppedImage = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: rect) {
            let trimmedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedImage, scale: scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
            
            // Print width and height of the trimmed image
            let trimmedWidth = Int(trimmedImage.size.width)
            let trimmedHeight = Int(trimmedImage.size.height)
            print("Trimmed image size: \(trimmedWidth) x \(trimmedHeight)")
            
            // Save the trimmed image to the camera roll
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(trimmedImage, nil, nil, nil)
        }
        
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }


Please create a minimal example.
